# useEffect received a final argument during this render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am getting this warning:

> Warning: useEffect received a final argument during this render, but not during the previous render. Even though the final argument is optional, its type cannot change between renders.

[warning screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeRaN.png)

```
//importing ...

const Relevance = () => {
  const { data, setData } = useContext(defaultData);

  if (data.length > 0) {
    const Relevance = data.map((d) => {
      return d.relevance;
    });

    const maxValue = Math.max(...Relevance);

    let HashRelevance = new Array(maxValue + 1).fill(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < Relevance.length; i++) {
      if (Relevance[i] !== null) {
        HashRelevance[Relevance[i]]++;
      }
    }

    var keyRelevance = [];
    var valueRelevance = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < HashRelevance.length; i++) {
      if (HashRelevance[i] !== 0) {
        keyRelevance.push(i);
        valueRelevance.push(HashRelevance[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  const [keyRelevanceState, setKeyIntenstityState] = useState([]);
  const [valueRelevanceState, setValueIntenstityState] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setKeyIntenstityState(keyRelevance);
  }, keyRelevance);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValueIntenstityState(valueRelevance);
  }, valueRelevance);
  if (valueRelevanceState !== undefined && valueRelevanceState.length > 0) {
    return (
        returning component...
    )
};

export default Relevance;
```

What is the error about?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry for not mentioning code... new to stackoverflow... btw code added!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is telling you that you're not passing a consistent value to `useEffect` as its final (second) argument (the optional dependency array) between renders. The dependency array argument you pass `useEffect` must either *always* be an array of dependencies (with the same length), or *always* be `undefined` (because you left it off, usually), on every render of your component.

You have this code:

```
if (/*...a condition...*/) {
    // ...
    var keyRelevance = [];
    // ...
}
// ...
useEffect(() => {
   // ...
}, keyRelevance);
```

That's functionally identical to:

```
var keyRelevance;              // ***
if (/*...a condition...*/) {
    // ...
    keyRelevance = [];         // ***
    // ...
}
// ...
useEffect(() => {
   // ...
}, keyRelevance);
```

That means you're declaring a `keyRelevance` variable that will initially have the value `undefined`, and then only assigning an array to it if a condition is met. Then you're using `keyRelevance` as the dependencies array.

The second argument to `useEffect` should be an *array* of dependencies, not just a single dependency, so wrap `keyRelevance` in an array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setKeyIntenstityState(keyRelevance);
}, [keyRelevance]);
// ^            ^
```

More [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

But separately, since you're creating a new array every time, that would cause the effect to change every time. Instead, memoize the creation of `keyRelevance` (and similar) using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) or [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) (since `useMemo`'s documentation says it's **just** for performance optimization, and in your case you need to memoize the value for *correctness*, not just optimization).

For instance:

```
const relevanceInfo = useRef(null);
// (Probably put this condition in a function)
if (!relevanceInfo ||
    data.length !== relevanceInfo.sourceData.length || 
    data.some((d, index) => d.relevance !== relevanceInfo.sourceData[index].relevance)) {
    relevanceInfo.keyRelevance = /* ...build the array... */;
    relevanceInfo.sourceData = data;
}

// ...
useEffect(() => {
    // ...
}, [relevanceInfo.keyRelevance]);
```

...or similar.

---

Side note: I wouldn't declare the variable *inside* the `if` block and then use it *outside* the `if` block. Instead, declare it in the top scope where it'll be used (in this case function scope). (Also, I suggest using `let` and `const`, not `var`; `var` is effectively deprecated and shouldn't be used in new code.)

Comment: thanks, I learn a lot from your single post.

My useEffect dependancy array is changing its length every time so I am getting this warning. 
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.

so my question is rn I want to update my state only after getting the whole data in keyRelevanceState how can I do that any suggestions or patterns you have?

and I have revised my code with the best practices you mentioned of variable(let, const) although I know about it and using let before but the moment I got error of undefined due to scope, I simply used var over it XD.

Comment: @MohammadFarhan - I should have thought of that with your rebuilding `keyRelevance` on every render. I've updated to point you in the right direction on that, but beyond that I'll have to suggest you read through the React documentation, work through their tutorial, etc. (I also suggest using standard JavaScript naming conventions for your variables; only constructor functions start with an upper case character.) Happy coding!

Comment: I am able to fix the issue, by defining a false flag at the top, once data of array got value from context I turn the flag true. and I am passing the flag into useEffect. does this pattern is Okay I am new to contextAPI I have a thorough knowledge in react. I think SO XD but still a lot to learn? and I have also fixed the naming conventions pf variable. In the THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @MohammadFarhan - To me that doesn't sound right, but it's hard to tell from a description (and I haven't used context much). It may be worth writing it up (with a [mcve], which [can use React](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/)) for https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but only after [reading their help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help). Happy coding!

Comment: @MohammadFarhan - No complaints here, you immediately responded to feedback by adding your code, etc.! Thanks for that, by the way. It so much more rare than you might think. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Final value, (second parameter) of the useEffect should be in array of different values or empty array. You are providing a `valueRelevance`  as final value of useEffect which itself an array but not in array , like below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setKeyIntenstityState(keyRelevance);
}, [valueRelevance]);
```

Or,

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        setKeyIntenstityState(keyRelevance);
    }, [param1, param2]);
```